# Compiles/runs fine but publishing fails: Could not find file 'Images\ajax-loader.gif' - how to correct this?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Output when attempting to publish:

```
2>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
2>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3010,5): Error : Copying file Images\ajax-loader.gif to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Images\ajax-loader.gif failed. Could not find file 'Images\ajax-loader.gif'.
```

I do a search in my solution and there's no reference to ajax-loader.gif anywhere. When I double-click on the last line of the output, Visual Studio takes me to Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets and the following section within:

```
<CopyPipelineFiles PipelineItems="@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)"
                       SourceDirectory="$(WebPublishPipelineProjectDirectory)"
                       TargetDirectory="$(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)"
                       SkipMetadataExcludeTrueItems="True"
                       UpdateItemSpec="True"
                       DeleteItemsMarkAsExcludeTrue ="True"
                   Condition="'@(FilesForPackagingFromProject)' != ''">
  <Output TaskParameter="ResultPipelineItems" ItemName="_FilesForPackagingFromProjectTempory"/>
</CopyPipelineFiles>
```

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image was referenced in the project file but had been deleted. Oddly enough the file was marked as "do not copy" but the VS publisher still wants it to exist before it goes on to ignore it.